# How to cast empty column in union to date?

Tags: postgresql

[Beginner at SQL]

I have sql query that looks like this:

```
select * from 
(select '' as dates from table1

union 

select dates from table2)
```

when I run this query i get error `UNION types text and timestamp without time zone cannot be matched`.

I tried to cast `dates` column in table 2 to varchar but thats not what I want. How can I cast the empty field in table1 as datetime?

I tried this:

```
select * from 
(select cast(('' as dates) as date) as dates from table1

union 

select dates from table2)
```

but that doesnt work either.

Comment: `select cast(null as timestamp) as dates from table1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give it the `null` value. And this can be cast to any data-type.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (
    SELECT null::timestamp AS dates FROM table1
    UNION
    SELECT dates FROM table2
) t
```

Note: instead of the `SELECT` for the "empty" date, you could also use a `VALUES`.